# How to pass variable to an async function in another file called in Promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

How can I pass a variable to an async function in another file within a promise?

```
// file1.js

const thisFunc = require('./file2');
const foo = "bar";

const newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   thisFunc
       .asyncFunction() // <-- I want to pass foo here
       .then(...)
}
```

```
// file2.js

const asyncFunction = async () => {
 console.log(foo); // <-- and do stuff with foo here
}

module.exports.asyncFunction = asyncFunction
```

Comment: What makes you think you can’t pass it the regular way? (Since you can afaik)

Comment: FYI, manually wrapping a `new Promise()` around an existing promise chain is an anti-pattern (as there is no reason to do so).  You can just return the existing promise chain.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the variable like you would any other - asynchronous activity doesn't prevent you from doing that:

```
thisFunc
    .asyncFunction(foo)
    .then(...)
```

Then add a parameter in `asyncFunction`:

```
const asyncFunction = async foo => {...};
```

Answer (score 0):

the async function will not stop you for passing data to async function.

```js
// file2.js

const asyncFunction = async (foo) => {
    console.log(foo); // <-- and do stuff with foo here
}

// file1.js
// const thisFunc = require('./file2');
const foo = "bar";
const newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // thisFunc.
    asyncFunction(foo) // <-- I want to pass foo here
        .then((data)=>{
            console.log(data);
            resolve('From newPromise ');
        })
});

newPromise.then(console.log);
```